# Kotlin : Read databse using LiveData Show me empty RecycleView

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm  use Room database, LiveData, and ViewModel in my project with Kotlin . i have Prepopulate database that i created before. my goal is read this database and show data in database into the recycle view with using Room.
so i copy database in asset folder and use `.createFromAsset`  method . when i run project database copying in path `data/data/packagename`.my problem is when i run project its show me nothing in my recycleveiw. i check code several time and see many example but every time it show me empty recycleview and never show my database information. im really confused and cant find where is my problem. can u tell me where is my wrong ? thankyou. here is my code :

Recycleview adapter :

```
       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RoomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if(holder is RoomViewHolder) {
        val current = entitys[position]
     
        holder.placeNameTextView.text = current.name
    }
}

internal fun setentitiys(entitis: List<Detail_Entity>) {
    this.entitys = entitys
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount() = entitys.size

inner class RoomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var placeNameTextView: TextView = itemView.placeNameTextView

}
```

Comment: It seems like you're on right track. Are you sure you have data in table ? Can you check with database inspector ?

Comment: @M D yes. when i copy  database from data/data/package name from emulator storage to my pc and opened with database inspector i see my table with all my data inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Room_Adapter**

```
internal fun setentitiys(entitis: List<Detail_Entity>) {
    this.entitys = entitis //Notice this !!
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

**Entity Class**

- Set Primary Key : @PrimaryKey. It's required.
- You used the table name 'my_table' in Detail_Dao. So add @Entity(tableName = "my_table")

Comment: my entity and dao class is ok. its just left from copy/paste. so  u say "add new Entity_detail object in LiveData list if you want to observe it" . how can i do that?

Comment: No, You won;t need to do it. I have updated the answer.